# Crystal Report - Report Formatting

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

[image: I want to Format my Crystal report as looking in yellow colour.]

I want to format my Report as shown in yellow colour. But I got what you see in blue colour.

Can anyone please help me to format my Crystal Report as shown in yellow colour?

[image: My Crystal Report Format]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right Click on Your Field**

**Then follow these steps:**

1. Select Formate Object
2. Go to common tab
3. Select Suppress if duplicate

   [image: enter code here]